# accidentally typed large number before Vim command, how to cancel?

Tags: vim

Short story: when I type a very large number before a command in Vim, how do I cancel it while it's running?

Long story:
I wanted to quickly note a large number, an ID like 949494. I quickly switched to my MacVim 7.4 and started typing, forgetting **for the first time in my life** to go into insert mode.

So I type `949494`.

Then I notice I'm in command mode, so I press `i` to go into insert mode, and then I type `949494` again.

And then, I realize what I've done*.

I'd had the time to stare at my screen for a while and even come here and start writing this question before Vim gave a reaction.

So how do I cancel this?

However, just looking at this familiar stackexchange interface with its blank question form and list of related questions, the answer came to me (it's really obvious). So as I type this I no longer have the question, but I thought it might be useful to ask anyway, and post my answer. Feel free to delete this if it sounds stupid.

* in other words, I've asked Vim to insert "949494" 949494 times.

Comment: See also http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10224/5298

Answer (score 1):

To cancel a running command in Vim, press `Ctrl+C`.

From vimhelp.appspot.com:

> CTRL-C
>
> Interrupt current (search) command.  Use CTRL-Break on MS-DOS dos.
>   In Normal mode, any pending command is aborted.

Comment: Or `Esc`. Or `Ctrl+[`.

Comment: @DmitryFrank Those didn't work for me, but maybe. I guess I should look it up in the docs.